# Issues running python scripts in Command Prompt (Specifically with command line arguments)?

Tags: python, scripting, command-prompt

I am trying to run my python scripts in the command-prompt without calling python.exe first. I am specifically doing this in relation to running django-admin.py. I have C:\Python26 and C:\Python26\Scripts in my PATH. However, if I try running django-admin.py by doing:

> django-admin.py startproject helloworld

I get the message: Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.

Now, after some experimentation, I realized the problem is that the secondary arguments to these scripts are not being passed for some reason, since I tried it with a some other python scripts I have. I know I could avoid this problem by simply doing:

> python C:\Python26\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject helloworld

But I know it should be possible to run the first command only and get it to work, because I had it working before. I've looked everywhere, and not many places have been helpful so any idea would be useful for me at this point.

Update: The .py file associations were set correctly, and the problem is still occuring.

Comment: DOS? I'm surprised that Django would work in DOS, seeing as how there's a distinct lack of sane TCP/IP support.

Comment: Probably safe to assume that OP means MS-DOS on Windows, as there hasn't been a port of Python to real DOS since 2.4.  Which was capable of networking, actually.  But it brought its own sockets library and drivers with it, as DOS has neither.

Comment: the OP surely means "command prompt".

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant MS-DOS or command prompt. Was really tired when I wrote this question.

Comment: I am having same problem with Django 1.1.1 and Python 2.5

Answer (score 4):

Check `assoc` and `ftype`.  If properly set, you can run a `.py` with arguments.

```
> assoc .py
.py=Python.File
> ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Depending on how your Python was installed, these may or may not be in place.  You can **set** them with `assoc` and `ftype`.

```
> assoc .py=Python.File
> ftype Python.File="C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Also, if `.py` is included in the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you can run `.py` files without the trailing `.py`.

```
> set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.py
> django-admin startproject helloworld
```

Comment: I've checked and all of those were set properly but I am still having the same issue. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python but that didn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I have searched for a few weeks for this very same problem and found nothing. 
Today, however, I tried something new:

If you are using Windows 7, do not use Command Prompt for scripting purposes.

Instead, use the Windows PowerShell located at: `All Programs -> Accessories ->  Windows PowerShell -> Windows PowerShell`. In there you can run the command `django-admin.py startproject mysite` if you added the correct paths to your environmental paths.

BTW, I'm now using Python 2.7 with Django 1.2.4 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit.